# Trying to get the full path for an image.... trying @url.Content(..... but issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to get the full path for an image. My first attempt is :

```
<img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/Logos/" + Model.ImageName + ".png")" />
```

This produces:

```
<img alt="" src="/Uploads/Logos/Image1.png" />
```

Which is not good enough. I really need the full URL like:

```
<img alt="" src="http://localhost/Uploads/Logos/Image1.png" />
```

or:

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.liveserver.com/Uploads/Logos/Image1.png" />
```

So need the http and server bit adding on.

What would be the approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an HTML helper extension for this:

```
public static class Helpers
{
  public static Uri FullyQualifiedUri(this HtmlHelper html, string relativeOrAbsolutePath)
  {
    Uri baseUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    string path = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(relativeOrAbsolutePath, new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
    Uri instance = null;
    bool ok = Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, path, out instance);
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
<img alt="" src='@Html.FullyQualifiedUri("~/Uploads/Logos/" + Model.ImageName + ".png")' />
```